# Changing similarity in lucene FuzzyQuery

Tags: java, lucene, fuzzy-search

I'd like to change the similarity before searching index. What I do is:

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_43, "field", standarAnalyzer);
System.out.println("similarity before: " + parser.getFuzzyMinSim());
parser.setFuzzyMinSim(0.6f);
System.out.println("similarity after: " + parser.getFuzzyMinSim());
Query query = parser.parse(inputString); // inputString is given by the user
System.out.println("Querystring: " + query.toString());
```

and now, when inputString = "something~" then I get this output

```
similarity before: 2.0
similarity after: 0.5
Querystring: field:something~2 // Why 2!?
```

My questions:

1. Why the similarity is set to 2.0 at the beginning (I thought it is 0.5 by default)?
2. Why after calling setFuzzyMinSim method it is still 2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FuzzyQuery` has been significantly changed in Lucene version 4.  The number there after the '~' is a maximum edit distance, not a minimum similarity.  I'm not really clear on how `FuzzyMinSim` is mapped to a maximum edit distance, as when the `StandardQueryParser` generates a `FuzzyQuery`.  Note that using [DefaultFuzzyMinSim](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html#defaultMinSimilarity) in 4.x is deprecated.

An edit distance of 2 is the default maximum, and edit distances greater than 2 are not supported by the `FuzzyQuery` class, and thus are not supported by the standard query parser.

Comment: I used luke to get to know what queries are generated with different similarities. This tool is really helpful. The distance is set to 2 when the similarity is in reange [0-0.66(6)7), in range [0.66(6)7-1] it is set to 1.

Comment: Michael McCandless, author of Lucene in Action, discusses the changes to FuzzyQuery in Lucene 4.0 on his blog. The new implementation is significantly faster. http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/03/lucenes-fuzzyquery-is-100-times-faster.html